# Is there a way to use a conditional "type guard" type in a generic argument?

Tags: typescript, ngrx

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFMGMBsEMBOBLAdgc1AZwPYFtJRodUsAXReNM0SRRHRUArLedSLAKEgA8AHRjWKkaSSgE8sAQUSQAcjjLTYsHAHdIAEwCyWTAF4uoUAHJx8KaCSFUS66o3bQaa9DLISROfDKMspgDcXGQS-ISykjJyisqOmlqgBqCh4TgAZtb0ltEKSipqCXrowTwCQkQk5ClhkAAKDOGIoQCSWLEFTrr6ScZmqYT8jXShLligdmLxzq7w7p6o3pC+-kEhtaAAKrUNOE2t7fnTickDGTXhu-sSbR3HxaV8gs2VorR4-KEA8gBGAFYwMi5O6FbTFXomUyQD6jHD-QHjGwTezwY4uRZzDxeaA+PyIALBAagACiMIkvwB7mBR1BJwukHO0M+5PhVNkeTitIeXC4IC2AAtCCJyJRqKAvEM9twnhUiSCugBhQXQADWAB5NrReGRIKgtOM4ZSyAA+JJbLU6vWI1ASADaAF0+gB+UCRHLs+UJPoALnNfEt+tAAG96b74DbQABfZ1bHbDZo3Q6cro+0AqyASc6a-26wOoSAANzoMdJzIpCI9NJTJl9AFdUCq7OpUI9yi9qHR0nMIvMSArcYwrlgNaag30APrwLC+0yS-gEif8X2bYLR3lgaRYAC0yCwABpQHPxlocJxkWJWCMUoLQJ7tEqYCrxYs6mVnjR0vXe4sj2q6hbcwNVkTQACgASl9aRv37ZY8SHP9Rz6OQyFrRBFhDSdpzMI9TAPccl1AestEgdI0G0ABCKNVx5PkACFaxoTQiHDUxhGQRBoFrJBYAkaxLxeMhBTwAA6UA2mvOhCFwAhxUEuhmBgflw13PAUhwUAT2vXcnTfCpP1Qb9sHgdJ6kaYd-xzK1byrBIH1VBDjXAyDoIHRB4LqRCTGQ1D0NATCZxwvCCKIkiyK0SjI2o9dsH5HBa1gRIfkINAC1RZAtC4YUaGk0ypTNX8QwGX0RTQTBI0csDAiAA)

I have a function, `props`, which takes in a single generic argument to be used by later consumers.

```js
export function props<P extends object>(): ActionCreatorProps<P> {
  // the value returned isn't important; props is mainly used to consume type information
  return { _as: 'props', _p: undefined! };
}
```

I want to assert that the type passed in for the generic argument does not violate the following definition:

```js
export type NotAllowedCheck<T extends object> = T extends any[]
  ? ArraysAreNotAllowed
  : T extends { type: any }
  ? TypePropertyIsNotAllowed
  : keyof T extends never
  ? EmptyObjectsAreNotAllowed
  : unknown;
```

But I can't simply do the following because it violates a circular constraint:

```js
export function props<P extends NotAllowedCheck<P>>(): ActionCreatorProps<P> {
  return { _as: 'props', _p: undefined! };
}
```

Is there some mechanism that allows these types of assertions in Typescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break the circular dependency by introducing another generic type (although it does look clumsy)

```
  function safeProps<P extends (R extends any ?
    P extends object ?
      NotAllowedCheck<P>
      : unknown
    : unknown)
    , R = any>(): ActionCreatorProps<P>
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEBEFMGMBsEMBOBLAdgc1AZwPYFtJRodUsAXReNM0SRRHRUArLedSLAKEgA8AHRjWKkaSSgE8sAQUSQAcjjLTYsHAHdIAEwCyWTAF4uoUAHJx8KaCSFUS66o3bQaa9DLISROfDKMspgDcXGQS-ISykjJyisqOmlqgBqCh4TgAZtb0ltEKSipqCXrowTwCQkQk5ClhkAAKDOGIoQCSWLEFTrr6ScZmqYT8jXShLligdmLxzq7w7p6o3pC%20-kEhtaAAKrUNOE2t7fnTickDGTXhu-sSbR3HxaV8gs2VorR4-KEA8gBGAFYwMi5O6FbTFXomUyQD6jHD-QHjGwTezwY4uRZzDxeaA%20PyIALBAagACiMIkvwB7mBR1BJwukHO0M%205PhVNkeTitIeXC4IC2AAtCCJyJRqKAvEM9twnhUiSCugBhQXQADWAB5NrReGRIKgtOM4ZSyAA%20JJbLU6vWI1ASADaAF0%20gB%20UCRHLs%20UJPoALnNfEt%20tAAG96b74DbQABfZ1bHbDZo3Q6cro%200AqyASc6a-26wOoSAANzoMdJzIpCI9NJTJl9AFdUCq7OpUI9yi9qHR0nMIvMSArcYwrlgNaag30APrwLC%200yS-gEif8X2bYLR3lgaRYAC0yCwABpQHPxlocJxkWJWCMUoLQJ7tEqYCrxYs6mVnjR0vXe4sj2q6hbcwNVkTQACgASl9aRv37ZY8SHP9Rz6OQyFrRBFhDSdpzMI9TAPccl1AestEgdI0G0ABCKNVx5N8Kk-VBv2weB0nqRph3-HMrVAECACUAK48MJFAJ0%20hMDjtUA8VgOE0STFvKsEgfVUENkmtCIbJtUFkusNI0VAwNkg8%20OSQTjXAyDoIHRB4LqU1gyQyAULQ4NQEwmccLwgiiJIsitEoyNqPXbB%20RwWtYESH5CDQAtUWQLQuGFGhcAIIczTYFj4JDAZfRFNBMEjMywOCIA)

Comment: Since `R` is defaulted to `any` and not inferrable, this does not assert anything on `P` unless `R` is directly provided.

Comment: I would link the playground that shows this but the url is too long for a SO comment >_>

Comment: @DavidShortman it works for the example you've given in your post (check the link I added)

Comment: Wow, I must've implemented it wrong. I can see it works!

Comment: Ah, I see how it works now, too. `R extends any` is always true, and with that out of the way you can now apply the constrain to P.
That's pretty wild!

Comment: Yeah, it is a bit of a mind twisting hack :) Glad it worked for you.

Comment: I'd love to credit your GitHub for the commit that I used this knowledge in, if you want- https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/3060

Comment: David, I checked out your PR and your end solution looks much simpler! Not sure there is anything to credit me for really :)

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about using check helper in the return type?

```js
// Declaring some constraint error messages
export const arraysAreNotAllowedMsg =
  'arrays are not allowed in action creators';
type ArraysAreNotAllowed = typeof arraysAreNotAllowedMsg;

export const typePropertyIsNotAllowedMsg =
  'type property is not allowed in action creators';
type TypePropertyIsNotAllowed = typeof typePropertyIsNotAllowedMsg;

export const emptyObjectsAreNotAllowedMsg =
  'empty objects are not allowed in action creators';
type EmptyObjectsAreNotAllowed = typeof emptyObjectsAreNotAllowedMsg;

// The constraint on props
export type NotAllowedCheck<T> = T extends object ? T extends any[]
  ? ArraysAreNotAllowed
  : T extends { type: any }
  ? TypePropertyIsNotAllowed
  : keyof T extends never
  ? EmptyObjectsAreNotAllowed
  : unknown : never

export interface ActionCreatorProps<T> {
  _as: 'props';
  _p: T;
}



export function safeProps<P>(): ActionCreatorProps<NotAllowedCheck<P>> {
  return { _as: 'props', _p: undefined! };
}

// ActionCreatorProps<"type property is not allowed in action creators">
const someProps = safeProps<{ type: string }>();
```

Comment: This modifies the return value to have the `TypePropertyIsNotAllowed` string in the generic type, but it doesn't actually throw an error.